# ‘I wish it to be clearly understood’ Vs. 'I wish it is clearly understood'?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between

> ‘I wish **it to be** clearly understood’

and

> 'I wish **it is** clearly understood'?

The second sentence was taken from [Oxford dictionary - 2.1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wish), and it is not clear to me structurally.I want to search about this structure on internet but the problem that I don't know even from where to start or what this kind of sentence is called.

Answer (score 1):

"I wish it is clearly understood" doesn't seem proper to this American speaker.  No offense to one of the world's great dictionaries!

I can't quite accept that the intended meaning is the same as in the earlier sentence.

"I wish it to be clearly understood" expresses a desire that the listener or reader should grasp the speaker's (or writer's) meaning, or agree with the latter's argument.

"I wish it is clearly understood" *seems* to be a way of expressing regret that "it" is *not* understood, or understood only imperfectly.  In this instance, I would use the subjunctive, as in:  "I wish that it *were* clearly understood."

Comment: The **first** sentence was taken from the ODE (which isn't the same dictionary as the OED but is nevertheless excellent). Further, the dictionary explains the structure by prepending the definition with "[with object and infinitive]" – so this is simply the way (a *formula* of sorts) the verb can be used to express the meaning ("Want (something) to be done or happen.").